# View is not showing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

if (INTERFACE_IS_IPHONE5) {
    CGPoint center = _canvas.center;
    CGRect frame = _canvas.frame;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.height = 568;
    _canvas.frame = frame;
    _canvas.center = center;
}
```

When rotate the screen the image does not show full width of the iPhone. I am think this line of code in the view did load is causing it. Trying to update the app for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the method for landscape and portrait mode. Refer this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)